# Non-exclusive use of bluetooth controller on host and container

Tags: bluetooth, dbus

I am successfully able to use `btmgmt` and `btmon` on a root-less container and whilst the host is still connecting to bluetooth devices. Yay!

However, when using `bluetoothctl` I am only able to use it if the `bluetooth` service is stopped on the host.

Looking at diagnostic information for `bluetoothd`

`bluetoothd[17345]: src/adapter.c:set_blocked_keys_complete() Successfully set blocked keys for index 0`

Makes me think that `bluetoothd` sets up some sort of exclusivity, even though btmgmt/btmon do not.

I am hoping to be able to use the bluetooth controller inside of the container (for development purposes via vscode devcontainers), whilst using bluetooth on the host (for keyboard / mouse).

This is both for personal ideals, but also I'm keen to understand the constraints to be able to provide guidance on a super clean developer's setup.

I have read that the homeassistant project utilizes dbus broker, is it because dbus itself has issues sharing? Other options include mapping dbus into the container, but that doesn't feel right, as I don't want to share the entire dbus.

I am yet to find a bluez config option which can help.

The main reason for wanting bluetoothctl to work, is that I am finding correlations between bluetoothctl working and Tmds.DBus working (i.e. being able to access it from user space code).